# Sql Server JDBC not Working on wildfly AS

Tags: sql-server, jboss, wildfly, datasource

Hi everyone I am trying to use the sqlserver jdbc with the wildfly AP , but when I try to test the connection after the datasource I always get this error :

```
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {
      "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql"],
      "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.Eventis is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/Eventis is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"
      ]
}}}
```

Here the content of the config files :

module.xml :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Standalone.xml :

```
<driver name="mssql" module="system.layers.base.com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

And finaly my jdbc jar file is located under this path :

wildfly-14.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main

Answer (score 1):

Your module name is not correct. It should be `com.microsoft.sqlserver`. The `standalone.xml` snippet should look like:

```
<driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

You can change this in CLI with the following command

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mssql:remove
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mssql:add(driver-name=mssql, driver-module-name="com.microsoft.sqlserver")
```